# Simulating power button press to display switch off dialog box

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

## I am trying to invoke the switch off dialog box that appears when we press power button. But i want to accomplish this task from an android application or a Junit test case. I will choose the most feasible approach in this case. I have been trying to do this but was not able to succeed. I am trying to use the following five approaches:
First approach:

```
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); boolean
                  dispateched = launcherButtonWInst.dispatchKeyEvent(new
                  KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) );
                  Log.i(LOG_TAG,String.valueOf(dispateched)); boolean
                  dispateched2=launcherButtonWInst.dispatchKeyEvent(new
                  KeyEvent(eventTime+2000, eventTime+2000, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) );
                  Log.i(LOG_TAG,String.valueOf(dispateched2));
```

=======================================================

## Second apporach:

```
private void generateKeys() {
        // Obtain the WindowManager system service interface
        IBinder wmbinder = ServiceManager.getService("window");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "WindowManager: " + wmbinder);
        IWindowManager wm = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(wmbinder);
        keyUpDown(wm, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER);
    }

    private void keyUpDown(IWindowManager wm, int keycode) {
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "keyDown: " + keycode);
            wm.injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keycode), true);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "keyUp: " + keycode);
            wm.injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keycode), true);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("ERROR!!!!!", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

============================================================

## Third approach:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER);
```

======================================================

## Fourth approach:

```
try {
                         long now =SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                         KeyEvent down = new KeyEvent(now, now,
                         KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER, 0);
                        
                         Log.d( LOG_TAG,down.toString() );
                         KeyEvent up = new KeyEvent(now+2000, now+2000,
                         KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER, 0);
                         Log.d( LOG_TAG,up.toString() );
                         (IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"))).injectKeyEvent(down,
                         true);
                         try {
                         Thread.sleep(2000);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         (IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"))).injectKeyEvent(up,
                         true);
                         } catch (RemoteException e) {
                         Log.d("LOGTAG",
                         "SendKeyEvent exception:"+e.getMessage());
                         }
```

================================================================

## Fifth approach:

```
try {
                    Context mContext = getBaseContext();
                    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(mContext);
                    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                    ShutdownThread.shutdown(mContext, true);
                   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR!!!", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

===================================================================

But none of them is working for me. The fifth approach is invoking shutdown() method of ShutdownThread class. But it gives me following error:

```
07-05 10:18:21.489: W/System.err(709): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@4104d798 -- permission denied for this window type
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:537)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at com.android.internal.app.ShutdownThread.shutdown(ShutdownThread.java:124)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at aexp.keygen.KeyGen$1.onClick(KeyGen.java:47)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-05 10:18:21.499: W/System.err(709):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-05 10:18:21.509: W/System.err(709):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Other approaches do not throw any error. I need help to accomplish this task, which ever way it takes even though I have to invoke native methods to accomplish I will do that, but I have to display the switch off UI.

Thanks

Ashwani

Comment: Hey app doesn't shut down, it stops saying "shutting down...". I used 5th method and is a system app.. how to proceed ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Sixth approach:

```
$ adb shell input keyevent 26
```

works!

### Seventh approach:

If you want the long press

```
$ adb shell <<!
> sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 107 1
> sleep 1
> sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 107 0
> exit
> !
```

You device may use a different input device than `/dev/input/event5`

### Eighth approach

This approach is a bit more clever and uses `sendevent` or `input keyevent` depending on API level.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import *

AdbClient(serialno='your-serial-number-here').longPress('POWER')
```

The advantage here is that this is a generic approach and can be used to send other keys too.
**AdbClient** is a python implementation of `adb` and is distributed with **[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)**.

Comment: it works but the problem is i want to perform a long click of the power button. How do i send that using ADB Shell

Comment: How about this i had tested this code on adb shell its working but when i tried to execute it through my application i got nothing    try {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 116 0");
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 116 1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 107 0\n");
DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
d.writeBytes("sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 107 1 \n");
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
 Log.i("PROCESSSTAT", line);
}
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
 Log.i("PROCESSSTAT", line);
}
I used above code to perform the task but its not working.

Comment: Fifth approach worked for me... when i signed the application as system application

Comment: @dtmilano How do you figure out which input device is being used by a particular phone?

Comment: The seventh approach needs to be updated for Jelly Bean as the ID for Power Button is 116 in Android 4.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar: how to sign application as system application?

Comment: @Mehul Joisar: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-devphone-updating/sSNXXY-yWLg/4yw4kmBTytwJ

Comment: for the android 4, the Seventh approach:  $ sendevent /dev/input/event6 1 116 1
$ sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
$ sendevent /dev/input/event6 1 116 0
$ sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0

Answer (score 7):

Other Approach

```bash
adb shell input keyevent --longpress KEYCODE_POWER
```