# Open power menu programmatically (Long click on power button)?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to open the power menu from within my application?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338022/simulating-power-button-press-to-display-switch-off-dialog-box)

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android,
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button

Comment: His question is the other way around - can he simulate the long press. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338022/simulating-power-button-press-to-display-switch-off-dialog-box

Comment: According to this post it's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957104/how-can-i-open-power-off-dialog-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public SDK access to open the power button menu programmatically, sorry.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if any way to power off programicaly